# MarketingCloudSDK SPM Module not supported by newer compilers

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios

It seems as though the way the MarketingCloudSDK Swift Package Module is built that it cannot be included in projects that use a different version of the Swift compiler. When trying to use the Swift Package for 8.0.3 in my team's project we get the following error:

`Failed to build module 'MarketingCloudSDK'; this SDK is not supported by the compiler (the SDK is built with 'Apple Swift version 5.4 (swiftlang-1205.0.26.9 clang-1205.0.19.55)', while this compiler is 'Apple Swift version 5.5.2 (swiftlang-1300.0.47.5 clang-1300.0.29.30)'). Please select a toolchain which matches the SDK.`

We are building with the latest Xcode, version 13.2.1.

There is an issue on Stack Overflow similar to this with possible resolution steps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70556401/swift-version-conflict-this-sdk-is-not-supported-by-the-compiler-please-select

Comment: I was able to build and archive an app with Xcode version 13.2.1 using swift version 5.5.2 and Marketing Cloud SDK 8.0.3. Is there a certain step or setting you are seeing this happen with?

Comment: Our project is very large so to isolate the problem I created a new empty project in Xcode that contained just a view controller and then included the Swift Package and tried to `import MarketingCloudSDK` and I get the same issue. So I don't believe it is any particular setting in our project.

Comment: Perhaps I should add that this is being built on an Intel MacBook for x86_64 simulator.

Comment: Im not saying your wrong, I am just unable to reproduce this error when using Xcode 13.2.1 and MarketingCloudSDK v8.0.3 and SFMCSdk v1.0.2 via SPM on an Intel based Mac. Do you have a link to a github project that demonstrates this error?

Can you provide a link to the project on github that is having this same error

Comment: I tried this on another Intel-based Mac with Xcode 13.2.1, empty project and I get the same error. Could you verify which version of the the Swift compiler you're Xcode is using via `xcrun swift -version`. Or perhaps the correctly built SDK is already cached in derived data and doesn't need to be built?

Comment: And here is a test project: https://github.com/wesselj1/Test-SFMarketingCloudSDK-SPM

Comment: I have verified I am using Swift compiler v5.5.2. I noticed on your sample app that you are only pulling in MarketingCloudSDK. That alone will not work. Via the documentation, when moving to MarketingCloudSDK v8.0+, be advised you will also need to bring in the (Core) SFMCSdk swift package. Ref: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-migration.html

Comment: Ah! Okay. That fixes it. I totally missed the notes on this migration. I always just reference this page https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/. I think it would be helpful if there was a callout somewhere in the body of that page about migrating with the link (other than just the sidebar). I wasn't aware there was any migration steps to update to from 7.x to 8+.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MarketingCloudSDK v8.x and above you also need to pull in the SFMCSdk Swift package. Migration steps outlined here: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-migration.html

Comment: These step are not clear, it will be nice if some one can add it into sample project as it crashing on some devices